# Storing data to array from worksheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to analyze some data from a worksheet, the first step was to find the last row, which I managed. Then I need to store the data in an array for each column to simplify further analysis.

My data looks like this:

[image: Data picture]

I'm trying to store let's say the B column in an array but starting at B6:

```
Sub List_Rem_stock()  

    Dim array_Rem_Batch(1 To last_row_Rem_stock - 5) As Integer

    For i = 1 To last_row_Rem_stock - 5
        array_Rem_Batch(i) = Worksheets("Rem stock").Range(Bi)
    Next i
    Debug.Print array_Rem_Index

End Sub
```

`last_row_Rem_stock` represents the last row of the table.
Am I doing this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost, try the code below (find explanation inside code's comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub List_Rem_stock()

Dim last_row_Rem_stock As Long, i As Long
Dim array_Rem_Batch() As Long

With Worksheets("Rem stock")
    last_row_Rem_stock = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with value in colum B

    ReDim array_Rem_Batch(1 To last_row_Rem_stock - 5) ' redim array size

    For i = 1 To last_row_Rem_stock - 5
        array_Rem_Batch(i) = .Range("B" & i).Value
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If there are 100 rows, this works just fine... but if you have thousands and more, iterating through each cell is not a good idea. The less you interact with the sheet, the better.

Comment: @FAB I am familiar with minimize interacting with the sheet, but actually reading a value from a sheet to an array, doesn't consume so much time. I have MACROs that I read 200,000 records to arrays, and it does so in few seconds. You should run a bench mark to test it

Comment: @FAB and by the way, this is really not a reason to down vote my answer, as the code is correct, and answers the **PO** question.

Comment: "Few seconds", several times can add up quite quickly to a minute, then few minutes. Is everyone's taste to be honest, but I prefer it to run faster than slower. As for your second comment, I would say that by posting a code that rectifies the OP, and it works, it doesn't necessarily mean is correct, nor that it answers the question. "Am I doing this properly?"  Being blunt, the correct answer was `NO`. As for how correct your answer is according to what OP asked, maybe you want to edit `.Range("B" & i).Value` to `.Range("B" & i + 5).Value`.

Comment: @FAB we are here to help users with their code issues, not to get in to argument who writes better code, but I guess not everyone is here for the same reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate a range to an array (2D) as such:

`Dim arrData as variant: arrData = Range("B1:B" & lastrow)`.

You can also put the array back on the spreadsheet the same way:

`Range("B1:B" & lastrow) = arrData`

Simple, easy and fast, without the need of iterating through data.

In your example, you would probably do it like this.

```vb
Sub List_Rem_stock()

    Dim i As Long, last_row_Rem_stock As Long
    Dim array_Rem_Batch As Variant
    
    With Worksheets("Rem stock")
        last_row_Rem_stock = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'get last row in B
        array_Rem_Batch = .Range("B1:B" & last_row_Rem_stock)
    End With

    For i = 6 To last_row_Rem_stock
         Debug.Print array_Rem_Batch(i, 1)
    Next i

End Sub
```

To note that arrays allocated this way will always start at 1, not 0.

**EDIT:**

I'm allocating the data starting at row 1, and not at row 6, purely for the nice 1:1 relation between array index and sheet rows. Is my prefered way, wherever the situation allows.

```vb
    If array_Rem_Batch(i, 1) = Range("B" & i) Then ....
```

Can always allocate the data from any row you want:

```vb
    array_Rem_Batch = Worksheets("Rem stock").Range("B6:B100") 'now the array has 95 rows.
```

In this case, array index 1, will corespond to row 6 in the sheet, and will have to manage this in the code if you need to something like this:

```vb
    If array_Rem_Batch(i, 1) = Range("B" & i + 5) Then ....
```

Comment: Great thanks! For the -5, because my list starts at B6, I thought I needed to dimension my array from 1 to the last row -5. If my last row is 100 then my list would actually have only 95 values?

Comment: See additional edit... you're right about the -5, to get the number of the rows, but in your example you allocated data in the array from row 1 to row 100 - 5. Should have been more like `For i = 6 to lastrow` instead, **or** `array_Rem_Batch(i) = Worksheets("Rem stock").Range("B" & i + 5)`.